# Does Yamato Cannon 1-hit kill an Immortal?

Tags: starcraft-2

Yamato Cannon deals 300 damage and Immortals have 100 shields and 200 hit points, but they also have a hardened shield ability that reduces incoming damage greater than 10 to 10. However, I am not sure if this applies to Yamato Cannon or if Yamato Cannon does reduced damage because of armor/shields.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Battlecruiser's Yamato Cannon will ignore the Immortals special ability and kill it in one shot.

I made this video to show it in action:

It also ignores armor, even with 3 in shield and armor the Immortal will be killed in 1 shot.

Comment: To explain: The immortals ability as well as armor or shield upgrades only protect against normal attacks, not against spell damage. The yamato cannon counts as spell so it ignores hardened shield and upgrades.

Comment: @dbemerlin I didn't realise that. It inspired me to do a little testing, and it appears all special abilities/spells, seem to ignore regular armor and shield armor.